# How do I write this set notation correctly?

Tags: matrices, elementary-set-theory

I have a 2D matrix $f(m,n)$, where $1<m<M$ and $1<n<N$. The element at location $(m,n)$ is denoted as $f_{m,n}\in \{+1,-1\}$. I want to write something like set notation but I am not really sure if which of the following is correct .

\begin{equation}
f_{m,n}\in \{+1,-1\}\mid 1<m<M,1<n<N\tag{1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
f_{m,n}\in \{+1,-1\}\forall 1<m<M,1<n<N\tag{2}
\end{equation}

or they are both incorrect.

Moreover, Is there a way to write $\mathbf{F}$ as a collection of all possible $f(m,n)$ of dimensions $M\times N$
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F} = \{f(m,n) \mid ???\}\tag{*}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you can write 
$$
f = (f_{m,n})_{\substack{1\leq m \leq M\\ 1\leq n\leq N}}\in\{+1,-1\}^{M\times N}
$$
and your $\mathbf{F}$ is this set: $\{+1,-1\}^{M\times N}$.

(Here, I allowed indices $1\leq n\leq N$ and $1\leq m\leq M$; the notation has to change slightly to get $1< n< N$ and $1< m< M$).

Comment: Can you please comment on the $(.)$ that you put around $f_{m,n}$. Are they there because of the dimensions which you had placed in subscript?

Comment: also should $f$ in the first line be $f(m,n)$, since that how I am naming a single matrix?

Comment: A matrix, say $f$, is basically a collection of elements indexed (here) by $m,n$. Formally, $f(m,n)$ or $f_{m,n}$ is just an *element* of the matrix, the element at index $(m,n)$. The notation $(f_{m,n})_{m,n}$ refers to the collection (tuple) of all such elements when $m,n$ vary, i.e. the matrix itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent your $f$ as a set.  You can think of it as a function from ordered pairs $(i,j)\to \{-1,+1\}$ and it is just the set $\{((i,j),\pm1)\}$, where in set theory a function is just a bunch of ordered pairs where there are no duplicates in the first element.  So you can say $f=\{((i,j),\pm1)|1\le i \le M, 1 \le j \ \le N\}$  Often whether $f(i,j)=+1 \text { or} -1$ depends on $i$ and/or $j$ in some interesting way, and your notation may obscure that.  Then $\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F} = \{f(m,n) \mid 1 \le m \lt \infty, 1 \le n \lt \infty\}\tag{*}
\end{equation}$

Comment: I am looking for a notation that does not hide anything. your definition for $\mathbf{F}$ represents the set of all possible $f(m,n)$ but says nothing about $f_{m,n}$.  That is why I will be going for Clement's answer. Thank you for your answer